# Import error while importing LogisticRegression from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am building a classification model for COVID-19 by using Logistic Regression. I am using jupyter notebook and I am importing Logistic Regression by `from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression`.
The following import error pops up.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-d98c89d6b4be> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
    80     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
    81     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 82     from .base import clone
    83     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
    84 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>
    18 
    19 from . import __version__
---> 20 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
    21 
    22 _DEFAULT_TAGS = {

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>
    25 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning
    26 from .deprecation import deprecated
---> 27 from .fixes import np_version
    28 from .validation import (as_float_array,
    29                          assert_all_finite,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in <module>
    16 import scipy.sparse as sp
    17 import scipy
---> 18 import scipy.stats
    19 from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
    20 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py in <module>
    382 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    383 
--> 384 from .stats import *
    385 from .distributions import *
    386 from .morestats import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in <module>
    183 import scipy.special as special
    184 from scipy import linalg
--> 185 from . import distributions
    186 from . import mstats_basic
    187 from ._stats_mstats_common import (_find_repeats, linregress, theilslopes,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py in <module>
    8 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    9 
---> 10 from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,
    11                                     rv_frozen)
    12 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py in <module>
    23 
    24 # for root finding for discrete distribution ppf, and max likelihood estimation
---> 25 from scipy import optimize
    26 
    27 # for functions of continuous distributions (e.g. moments, entropy, cdf)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py in <module>
    388 
    389 from .optimize import *
--> 390 from ._minimize import *
    391 from ._root import *
    392 from ._root_scalar import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in <module>
    28 from ._trustregion_krylov import _minimize_trust_krylov
    29 from ._trustregion_exact import _minimize_trustregion_exact
---> 30 from ._trustregion_constr import _minimize_trustregion_constr
    31 
    32 # constrained minimization

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\__init__.py in <module>
    2 
    3 
----> 4 from .minimize_trustregion_constr import _minimize_trustregion_constr
    5 
    6 __all__ = ['_minimize_trustregion_constr']

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\minimize_trustregion_constr.py in <module>
    2 import time
    3 import numpy as np
----> 4 from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
    5 from .._differentiable_functions import VectorFunction
    6 from .._constraints import (

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py in <module>
    114 from .dsolve import *
    115 from .interface import *
--> 116 from .eigen import *
    117 from .matfuncs import *
    118 from ._onenormest import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py in <module>
    9 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    10 
---> 11 from .arpack import *
    12 from .lobpcg import *
    13 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py in <module>
    20 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    21 
---> 22 from .arpack import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py in <module>
    43 __all__ = ['eigs', 'eigsh', 'svds', 'ArpackError', 'ArpackNoConvergence']
    44 
---> 45 from . import _arpack
    46 import numpy as np
    47 import warnings

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

#### In the same python installation I tried importing LogisitcRegression in Spyder and it is imported successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error messages, it looks like there are issues with `scipy` library.
Try uninstalling and reinstalling the library.

```
conda remove --force scipy

pip install scipy
```